# How to convert tif to map

Tags: gdal, geotiff-tiff, mapfile

I need to convert a `.tif` file into a `.map` format. How can I do it? Is it possible using GDAL?

Comment: What is .map? MapInfo TAB, Manifold project file, or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [this list](http://www.gdal.org/formats_list.html) the 'OziExplorer .MAP'-format is not supported for writing in GDAL.

If that is not actually the format that you are after, you can probably find the one you actually are looking for on the same list.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it easily in QGIS in raster> Conversion >translate (Convert Format)